# Cisco IOS: OSPFv3 route cost

Tags: cisco-ios, ospf, ipv6

Cisco IOS 12.4T and later: `show ip ospf rib` informs about the cost for each network learned by OSPFv2. What command does the equivalent for OSPFv3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `show ipv6 ospf rib`. Almost all `show ip *` commands have a `show ipv6` equivalent.

Comment: Indeed it works. The command seems to be hidden. It is not suggested by `show ipv6 ospf ?`. It is not filled in by `show ipv6 ospf ri` + <TAB>.

Comment: The IOS-XR equivilant is "show ospfv3 rib"